# mapping many-to-one in django and playframework

Tags: java, django, playframework, many-to-one

I need to model a Customer and an Address for applications in django as well as in Play!.I believe that two Customers can have the same address.

So a Many to One relation between Customer and Address

```
class Customer extends play.db.jpa.Model{

@ManyToOne
public Address address;

..
}
```

In django ,does this python code below give similar mapping?

```
class Address(models.Model):
   customer= models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

What will be the tables created like?I am slightly confused here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got that right. The [many-to-one relationship in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships) is indeed represented by the models.ForeignKey.

To express relationship that two customers can have the same address you would define that relation in the Customer model (not in the Address model as you assumed).

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
```